# Selenium cannot enable flash on chrome 63 java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have automated tests using Chrome, it worked on Chrome 62. Now with Chrome version 63, my tests don't work because the flash is not activated. 
The version of chromedriver is 2.53.

How can I always enable flash on chrome 63? Thanks a lot.
Here is my code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = Collections.singletonMap("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,.per_resource.adobe-flash-player",1);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: **The version of chromedriver is 2.53** ?

Comment: Yes. And on mac

Answer (score 0):

To enable **flash** on `Chrome 63.x` you can use the following block of code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.state.flash",1);    # 1->allow
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried with this code, there's always a icon next to the star at top-right of screen, saying "flash is blocked on this page"

Comment: Can you try with value of `0` once?

Comment: I tried with 0 and 1, it seems parameter 0 and 1 do the same thing.

Comment: How about the last trial with `2`?

Comment: Always failed... With chrome 62, I used  prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);     but it dosen't work now.

Answer (score 0):

So if its on Mac, so maybe You should change more options - I can see, than on Mac, there are 3 steps: https://support.digication.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003963468-Enabling-Flash-for-Google-Chrome-Windows-Macintosh-